# AS3 - Shooting Game - hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i'm about to finish my project for University. But I'm stuck with the `hittestobject`.

```js
var Player: gun = new gun();
Player.x = mouseX;
Player.y = mouseY;
addChild(Player);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mousemove);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shoot);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, release_shoot);

function mousemove(e: MouseEvent): void
{
 Player.x = mouseX + 200;
 Player.y = mouseY + 35;
}

function shoot(event: Event): void
{
 var Bullet: bullet = new bullet();
 /*var explosion:explo1 = new explo1(); */
 Bullet.x = Player.x;
 Bullet.y = Player.y;
 /* explosion.x = Player.x;
  explosion.y = Player.y;*/
 Player.rotationX = 5;
 Player.rotationY = 5;
 addChild(Bullet);
 /* addChild(explosion);*/
 Bullet.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBullet);
}

function release_shoot(event: Event): void
{
 var explosion: explo1 = new explo1();
 Player.rotationX = -5;
 Player.rotationY = -5;
}

function moveBullet(e: Event): void
{
 e.target.y -= 12;
 e.target.x -= 96;
 if (e.target.y <= -200 || e.target.x <= -200)
 {
  e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBullet);
  removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));
 }
}

function goesside_1(event: Event): void
{
 mc_target.x -= 2;
 if (mc_target.x < -20)
  mc_target.x = 550;
}
mc_target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, goesside_1);

function targeting(event: Event): void
{
 var bullet: MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
 if (bullet.hitTestObject(mc_target))
 {
  mc_burst.x = mc_target.x;
  mc_burst.y = mc_target.y;
  mc_burst.gotoAndPlay(2);
  mc_target.x = 200;
  mc_target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, targeting);
  mc_target.x = 200;
  trace("targerting");
 }
 else if (mc_target.x > 550)
  bullet.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, targeting);
 else
  bullet.y -= 12;
 bullet.x -= 96;
}
```

The bullet is going in the Target without any doubt, I see it haha... But won't replace `mc_target` with `mc_burst`.

**EDIT**

This is the working code I used for anyone who's interested:

```js
var Player:gun = new gun(); 
Player.x = mouseX; 
Player.y = mouseY; 
addChild(Player); 

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mousemove); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shoot); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, release_shoot); 
function mousemove(e:MouseEvent):void{ 
Player.x = mouseX + 200; 
Player.y = mouseY + 35; 
} 

function shoot(event:Event):void{ 
var bullet1:bullet = new bullet();
/*var explosion:explo1 = new explo1(); */
    bullet1.x = Player.x;
    bullet1.y = Player.y;
/*  explosion.x = Player.x;
    explosion.y = Player.y;*/
    Player.rotationX = 5;
    Player.rotationY = 5;
    addChild(bullet1); 
/*  addChild(explosion);*/
    bullet1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, targeting); 
} 

function release_shoot(event:Event):void{ 
var explosion:explo1 = new explo1(); 
    Player.rotationX =- 5;
    Player.rotationY =- 5;

}

function movebullet(e:Event):void{ 
e.target.y -= 12;
e.target.x -=96;/*When the function is called the targets Y position will be subract by 40 pixels every frame, this makes the movieclip move up. The target is the Bullet movieclip.*/
if(e.target.y <= -200 && e.target.x <= -200 ){ 
e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movebullet);
removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));
}
}
function goesside_1(event:Event):void {
    mc_target.x -= 2;
        if (mc_target.x < -20)
        mc_target.x = 550;
}
mc_target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, goesside_1);

function targeting(event:Event):void {
    var bullet1:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
    if (bullet1.hitTestObject(mc_target)){
        mc_burst.x = mc_target.y;
        mc_burst.y = mc_target.x;
        mc_burst.gotoAndPlay(2);
        mc_target.x = 200;
        mc_target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, targeting);
        mc_target.x = 200;
        trace("targerting");
    } 
    else if (mc_target.x > 550){
        bullet1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, targeting);
    }
    else{
    bullet1.y -= 12;
    bullet1.x -= 96;}

}
// REPLACING CURSOR BY A SIGHT //

import flash.ui.Mouse;

Mouse.hide();

var myCursor:sight = new sight();

myCursor.visible = false;

function init()
{
    addChild(myCursor);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeaveHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseLeaveHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseMoveHandler);

}

function mouseMoveHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    myCursor.visible = true;
    myCursor.x = evt.stageX + 10;
    myCursor.y = evt.stageY + 10;
}

function mouseLeaveHandler(evt:Event):void
{
    myCursor.visible = false;
}
init();
```

Comment: Do you get the "targeting" trace?

Comment: I wish i get it... But not at all it's why i placed it.
Is there a way i can send you my FLash ?

Comment: as an aside, you're missing curly brackets in your last else if/ else statements at the end of your posted code, since it's the last functional code in the block it will still work

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you are invoking that function (`targeting`) - seems like you mean to be attaching it to an Enter Frame event.

Comment: I just Fixed th {} and wont change a thing. Gonna check the targeting

Comment: +BadFeelingAboutThis YOU ARE A MONSTER THANKS SO MUCH... Maybe cause i spent so much time on the previous project ahaha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89941/discussion-between-arsenil98-and-badfeelingaboutthis).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code you've posted is everything,  the issue is that the `targeting` method is never called.

Seems like you want to add it as a handler for the enter frame event (as you are removing a listener to that end inside the method)

eg.

```
bulletInstance.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, targeting);
```

That said, looking at your code, you're going to want to combine your move and targeting functions (you don't want to keep collision checking after you've removed the bullet in your `moveBullet` function) - or at least remove the `targeting` enter frame listener when you remove the button from the screen.

Possibly something like this:

```
function removeBullet(b:MovieClip):void {
    b.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBullet);
    removeChild(MovieClip(b));
}

function moveBullet(e:Event):void { 
    var bullet:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);

    bullet.y -= 12;
    bullet.x -= 96;

    if(bullet.y <= -200 || bullet.x <= -200 ){ 
        removeBullet(bullet);
    }

    if (bullet.hitTestObject(mc_target)){
        mc_burst.x = mc_target.x;
        mc_burst.y = mc_target.y;
        mc_burst.gotoAndPlay(2);
        mc_target.x = 200;

        removeBullet(bullet);
        trace("targerting");
    } else if (mc_target.x > 550){  
        removeBullet(bullet);
    }
}
```

If you have many bullets, you'll probably want to have just one enter frame handler, and iterate through each bullet there - instead of having a separate enter frame handler for each bullet.

Also, I'm surprised you are not getting errors, because you have ambiguous naming going on.  You have a class called `bullet`, but then you create vars called `bullet` as well.    Standard practice in AS3 is the give your class names a capitol first letter, and your instance names a lowercase first letter.  I'd recommend you do this to avoid errors and ambiguous code.

Comment: May i ask you something else in private message ?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't have private messaging (and I don't give out contact information of any kind), but you can ask something in chat or as a comment

Answer (score -1):

I would like to thanks BadFeelingAboutThis for his fast help here.

So for people who want to use my code, go head it works now

```js
var Player:gun = new gun(); 
Player.x = mouseX; 
Player.y = mouseY; 
addChild(Player); 

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mousemove); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shoot); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, release_shoot); 
function mousemove(e:MouseEvent):void{ 
Player.x = mouseX + 200; 
Player.y = mouseY + 35; 
} 

function shoot(event:Event):void{ 
var bullet1:bullet = new bullet();
/*var explosion:explo1 = new explo1(); */
    bullet1.x = Player.x;
    bullet1.y = Player.y;
/*  explosion.x = Player.x;
    explosion.y = Player.y;*/
    Player.rotationX = 5;
    Player.rotationY = 5;
    addChild(bullet1); 
/*  addChild(explosion);*/
    bullet1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, targeting); 
} 

function release_shoot(event:Event):void{ 
var explosion:explo1 = new explo1(); 
    Player.rotationX =- 5;
    Player.rotationY =- 5;

}

function movebullet(e:Event):void{ 
e.target.y -= 12;
e.target.x -=96;/*When the function is called the targets Y position will be subract by 40 pixels every frame, this makes the movieclip move up. The target is the Bullet movieclip.*/
if(e.target.y <= -200 && e.target.x <= -200 ){ 
e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movebullet);
removeChild(MovieClip(e.target));
}
}
function goesside_1(event:Event):void {
    mc_target.x -= 2;
        if (mc_target.x < -20)
        mc_target.x = 550;
}
mc_target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, goesside_1);

function targeting(event:Event):void {
    var bullet1:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
    if (bullet1.hitTestObject(mc_target)){
        mc_burst.x = mc_target.y;
        mc_burst.y = mc_target.x;
        mc_burst.gotoAndPlay(2);
        mc_target.x = 200;
        mc_target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, targeting);
        mc_target.x = 200;
        trace("targerting");
    } 
    else if (mc_target.x > 550){
        bullet1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, targeting);
    }
    else{
    bullet1.y -= 12;
    bullet1.x -= 96;}

}
// REPLACING CURSOR BY A SIGHT //

import flash.ui.Mouse;

Mouse.hide();

var myCursor:sight = new sight();

myCursor.visible = false;

function init()
{
    addChild(myCursor);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, mouseLeaveHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseLeaveHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseMoveHandler);

}

function mouseMoveHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    myCursor.visible = true;
    myCursor.x = evt.stageX + 10;
    myCursor.y = evt.stageY + 10;
}

function mouseLeaveHandler(evt:Event):void
{
    myCursor.visible = false;
}
init();
```